# Como fazer Consulta Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Preciso pegar o ID da última postagem de um post_type, porém não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso no wordpress.
Já tentei `mysql_query()` mas não consegui.

```
$consulta = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='photo' ORDER BY ID DESC "));

$id = $consulta['ID'];
```

Mas não recupera o último ID

Answer (score 3):

Se quer mesmo fazer uma consulta no WordPress precisa usar o [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) que oferece já uma interface completa para tudo o que você precisar.

A sua consulta poderia ser feita da seguinte forma:

```php
global $wpdb;

$id = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'photo' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1" );
```

Veja que no caso utilizei `$wpdb->posts`, já que a instalação de cada um pode nem sempre ter o prefixo `wp_`. Além que se fosse necessário consultar uma tabela diferente das do padrão do WordPress deveria usar algo como:

```php
{$wpdb->prefix}nome_da_tabela
```

Outra coisa que mudei na sua consulta foi que fiz ela apenas para pegar o `ID`, já que não tem sentido consultar várias colunas se você precisa apenas de uma.

Exatamente por precisar apenas de um valor eu utilizei o método `$wpdb->get_var()`. Desta forma você não precisa se preocupar em extrair o valor de um objeto ou de um array.

Mas geralmente para fazer consultas em posts do WordPress você pode utilizar a classe [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) ou a função [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) (que cria uma interface para o `WP_Query`).

Answer (score 1):

Use a função `get_posts` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), e troque o parâmetro `post_type` para o nome do seu custom post type. Para pegar o último post, basta apenas trocar a variável `posts_per_page` para 1.

Exemplo:

```
<?php $post = get_posts(
array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_type' => 'meucustomposttype', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC')
);

foreach($post as $last_post) {
    echo $last_post->ID;
}
?>
```

O código acima retorna o ID do último post do custom post type "meucustomposttype".